# two objects have the same value

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Both object is the same when i edit.
show the solution to seprate objects.
i have an object and with v-model i bind it to inputs to update it but when i edit it but don't save changes the object is changed. for not occurring this situation i use a second object(temporary) when editing i use that object but again it changes the first object.

```
data(){
   return{
      user:{
        id:'',
        firstname:'',
        lastname: ''
      },
    tuser:{}
     }
  },
 mounted(){
     axios.get('/user')
         .then((response) => {
              this.user = response.data  
             })
         .catch(error)
    },
 methods:{
      edit(){
      this.tuser = this.user
      },
 update(){
      axios.patch(`/user/${this.tuser.id}`,this.tuser)
         .then((response)=>{
                 this.user = this.tuser
          })
       .error()
      }
 }
```

Comment: Your description is quite complex - Can you try to put some more time in question and explain your problem stepwise ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mutating a reference value, it doesn't matter which one you change - they both get updated as they share the same address in memory heap.

So Use ES6 `spread` to make clone when you are trying to have copy of any reference value.

```
this.user = { ...this.tuser }
```

or

```
this.tuser = { ...this.user }
```

References : [spread_es6](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely because you reference one object to another.
As objects are reference not primitive values.
What it means is:
if you make obj1 = obj2, then actually they both point to the same object, if you change one, another change also.
You need to use something like Object.assign()
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign

Answer (score 0):

```
methods:{
  edit(){
  this.tuser = this.user
  },
```

I think you just need to pass a cloned copy of this.user, you can achieve that using lodash/underscore.js methods like [clone](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#clone) or [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#cloneDeep). If you don't copy your object they are referencing the same object